# Angular 6 - ServiceWorker not requesting gzipped content

Tags: javascript, angular, gzip, service-worker

I recently added service worker to my Angular 6.0.3 app. Everything works great.

I observed a slight increased initial load time when app is loaded the first time and to my surprise, the mainxxxx.js file being downloaded was 3.1 MB.

Cloudfront gzips the js files reducing the size of main.xxx.js to around 500KB, but it will only gzip when the client will send the

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

request header. The browser was sending this header, but service worker requests don't have this header, which is a big problem because angular build files have very large size.

Is this a bug which will be fixed or service workers don't support gzip which would be a big disappointment.

**EDIT:**

Github tracking issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24227

Comment: Facing same issue. any solution for this?

Comment: @NisargThakkar It turned out that I forgot to enable compress content in cloudfront